# .NET Core API - method appears in Swagger UI locally but not in deployed version

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm working on an existing .NET Core API. I've created a new method and I can see the new method with the old methods and it works as expected through Swagger UI locally. The build has been deployed however I can't see the new method in Swagger UI on the deployed version. I can only see the old methods. Why might that be?

Swashbuckle setup:

```csharp
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "Test API", Description = "Test API", Version = "v1" });
            c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, @"TestAPI.API.xml"));
            c.OperationFilter<AddRequiredClientInstanceIdHeaderParameter>();
            c.OrderActionsBy(x => x.HttpMethod);
        });
```

Comment: Without code, information how swagger is configured it is hard to tell.

Comment: @Hostel Updated OP with more info.

Comment: What do you mean that you see method - do you see it in generated swagger.json or SwaggerUI? If you talk about SwaggerUI then it's good to know how it's configured.